# How to create example of arrays in RAML v1.0

Tags: rest, api, documentation, ram, documentation-generation

I am trying to create an example of array in RAML v1.0.
I do not think it is specified in specification document. I can not find it there.

I need this output in resource example section:

```
{ tracks: 
    [{
      track:12
    },
    {
      track:121
    }]
 }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use this way...

```
tracks
type: array
items:
  properties: 
    releasedate: datetime
    album: string
    artist: string
    year: number
```